# Which message queue tools are recommended for using in a JRuby on Rails app using Trinidad?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, message-queue, torquebox, trinidad-gem

I'm a long time Torquebox user, but now I want to try using Trinidad for JRuby on Rails deployment. One of the best things of using Trinidad instead of Torquebox is that you may use Heroku :)

But Torquebox has a message queue feature using JMS and Trinidad doesn't have any MQ feature out-of-the-box. Anyone can recommend a MQ tool from JRuby on rails using Trinidad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Heroku, I would select a hosted message broker listed in the Heroku add-ons area. If you decide to host your own, you could install ActiveMQ or another broker onto one or more EC2 instances and set the security group to allow connections from Heroku's EC2 instances. Whatever method you choose, the next step is to simply configure your JRuby on Rails app to connect to the broker and publish/subscribe as desired.